# Connection to dbus session failed

Tags: terminal, debian, tmux, dbus

I am running Debian 6 with Gnome 2.30.2 (old, but it's the workstation I have to use). When I want to run dbus-monitor or any other dbus application from within `tmux`, I get an error:

```
$ dbus-monitor
Failed to open connection to session bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ZRKyYj013S: Connection refused
```

When I do not run things from within tmux, everything is fine. Can I work around this, while still using tmux?

Comment: This is fairly good enough documented. `export $(dbus-launch)` often helps. Check `xhost` from both out and inside `tmux`, and also use `xhost +` if needed.

Comment: The export works, thanks -- xhost was not neccessary. If you put that into an answer, I'll gladly upvote and accept it.

Comment: And one more question: Can I run the export command automatically, whenever I open a new shell in tmux? I think I don't want it in .bashrc. Maybe I test for $TMUX, and run this optionally.

Comment: In case aliasing it in .bashrc is that want you not, may [this question of mine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82632) help you.